# How to enable webpage to open through menu in joomla website

Tags: joomla

In my joomla website I have accidentally change some settings through admin panel for that in one menu all pages opening to root of website url:
My website url is mywebsite.in and in menu all pages opening to root of website(mywebsite.in/page1) instead of opening through menu(mywebsite.in/menu/page1)
How to make it open webpage through menu only?Please help me on that.

Answer (score 1):

add "page1" and so on as an sub-item of "menu". So "menu" is the Root item and all other are sub items. After that you have structure like this:

```
menu/page1
menu/page2
menu/page3...
```

In Menu-Manager it should show sub items with an "-" in front, like this:

```
menu
-page1
-page2
-page3
```

cheers and have fun!